# Number to Roman Numerals in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, roman-numerals

I recently started learning python.

**Requirements**

- Input: Integer between 1 and 3999
- Output: String with Roman numerals

I would appreciate it if someone could have look at the code and give me any feedback. I am particularly interested in the Python specific improvements, as I mainly programmed in C before.

**Edit**: Any feedback on the algorithm is appreciated too.

```
import sys

symbols1 =     [(1,   "I"), (5,   "V"), (10,   "X")]
symbols10 =    [(10,  "X"), (50,  "L"), (100,  "C")]
symbols100 =   [(100, "C"), (500, "D"), (1000, "M")]

symList = [symbols1, symbols10, symbols100]

def digitToRomanSym (digit, symList):
    """ Converts a single digit into its roman symbols """
    one =  symList[0][1]
    five = symList[1][1]
    ten =  symList[2][1]

    switcher = {
        1: one,
        2: one + one,
        3: one + one + one,
        4: one + five,
        5: five,
        6: five + one,
        7: five + one + one,
        8: five + one + one + one,
        9: one + ten,
    }
    return switcher.get(digit, "")

def getRomanNumerals (n):
    """ Converts a number between 1 and 3999 into Roman numerals """
    maxNumber = symList[-1][-1][0] * 4 - 1 # A symbol can be repeated max 3 times e.g. MMM for 3000

    if (n > maxNumber):
        return "Number too big"

    if (n == 0):
        return "Number too small"

    i = 0
    romanStr = ""
    while (n > 0 and i < len(symList)):
        romanStr = digitToRomanSym(n % 10, symList[i]) + romanStr
        n /= 10
        i += 1

    if (n > 0):
        biggestSymbol = symList[-1][-1][1]
        romanStr = (n * biggestSymbol) + romanStr;

    return romanStr

if (len(sys.argv) == 2):
    number = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(getRomanNumerals(number))
else:
    print("Wrong number of arguments")
```

Comment: Python 2 actually. It relies on `/=` doing integer division in `getRomanNumerals`, when doing `n /= 10`. Making it `n //= 10` gets it to work in Python 3.x.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the answer (by me) to this similar question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/138772/98493

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!

Most of my suggestions are stylistic, but still something to care about in the Python world.  ([PEP8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))  I did catch a fairly major bug since you are only accepting 1 - 3999 as valid numbers, so we fix that too.

---

**Redundant Parentheses**

Unlike in C or C++ (or even Java to some level) you don't have to wrap conditionals in parentheses typically.  There are some cases where you would need to, but your `if` conditions are not complex enough to need that.

---

**BUG: If an integer less than 0 is passed, there is no warning about being too small a number**

Therefore, if a negative number is passed in at runtime, it outputs nothing and no errors.  We can fix this in one line of code - we just change your `==` check to a `<=` check (less than or equal to):

```
if num <= 0:
    return "Number too small"
```

---

**Descriptive Parameters**

Normally, you should name an parameter for a function in a more descriptive way.  While `n` can be assumed to be a number, it would be better to have `num` instead of `n` as an parameter name for `getRomanNumerals` to better describe what that is.

My two cents, of course, but in more complex functions where `n` could lose meaning, you'd be better off with a more descriptive parameter name so you don't lose track of what `n` does.

---

**Rogue Semicolon!**

On line 47, you have a rogue trailing semicolon.  While this doesn't affect running of your program, such semicolons are not necessary.

---

**Style: Function names should be lowercase; multiword names separated with underscores**

From the PEP8 (linked above):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

Therefore, your function names should be renamed as follows:

- `digitToRomanSym` becomes `digit_to_roman_sym`
- `getRomanNumerals` becomes `get_roman_numerals`

---

**Style: Parameter variable names usually are lowercase**

While not explicitly defined in PEP8 as far as I can tell, most of the time, arguments within a function (for example, `symList` in `digitToRomanSym` in your code) tend to be lowercase and if multiword, are underscore-separated.

---

**Style: Local variable names should be lowercase, multiword separated with underscores**

Just like function definitions, local variables should be lowercase.  That is, variables within the scope of a single function.

---

---

**Your code after my changes:**

(Filename: `int2roman.py`)

```
import sys

symbols1 =     [(1,   "I"), (5,   "V"), (10,   "X")]
symbols10 =    [(10,  "X"), (50,  "L"), (100,  "C")]
symbols100 =   [(100, "C"), (500, "D"), (1000, "M")]

symList = [symbols1, symbols10, symbols100]

def digit_to_roman_sym (digit, sym_list):
    """ Converts a single digit into its roman symbols """
    one =  sym_list[0][1]
    five = sym_list[1][1]
    ten =  sym_list[2][1]

    switcher = {
        1: one,
        2: one + one,
        3: one + one + one,
        4: one + five,
        5: five,
        6: five + one,
        7: five + one + one,
        8: five + one + one + one,
        9: one + ten,
    }
    return switcher.get(digit, "")

def get_roman_numerals(num):
    """ Converts a num between 1 and 3999 into Roman numerals """
    max_number = symList[-1][-1][0] * 4 - 1 # A symbol can be repeated max 3 times e.g. MMM for 3000

    if num > max_number:
        return "Number too big"

    if num <= 0:
        return "Number too small"

    i = 0
    roman_str = ""
    while num > 0 and i < len(symList):
        roman_str = digit_to_roman_sym(num % 10, symList[i]) + roman_str
        num /= 10
        i += 1

    if num > 0:
        biggest_symbol = symList[-1][-1][1]
        roman_str = (num * biggest_symbol) + roman_str

    return roman_str

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    number = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(get_roman_numerals(number))
else:
    print("Wrong number of arguments")
```

Comment: Thanks for the review, I will look at it in detail later today. Just a quick question, is camelcase not pythonic?

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen No sense CamelCase is part of PEP8